# How can I get two distance with Arangodb?

Tags: database, arangodb

I want to query n find two distance.

[image: example graph]

This is my AQL so far:

```
FOR start IN @@vertexCollection
  FOR v, e, p IN 0..2 ANY 'circles/L' @@edgeCollection
    FILTER p.vertices[2]._key == 'n'
    RETURN {
      source: start,
      destination: v,
      edges: p.edges,
      vertices: p.vertices
    }
```

Comment: https://github.com/arangodb/Cookbook/blob/master/recipes/AQL/MigratingEdgeFunctionsTo3.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You only need the traversal (inner loop)
- You need a depth of 0..3 for the path: L -> 601 -> m -> n
  (0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3)
- Your filter has to check the last vertex and not the second

Your AQL should look like:

```
FOR v, e, p IN 0..3 ANY 'circles/L' GRAPH 'yourGraph' 
  FILTER p.vertices[-1]._key == 'n' 
    RETURN p
```

**UPDATE**

More easier is to use `v` in your filter which is the last vertex in the path.

```
FOR v, e, p IN 0..3 ANY 'circles/L' GRAPH 'yourGraph' 
  FILTER v._key == 'n' 
    RETURN p
```